# When calendar event taking place, python outputs

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create (or find) a calendar for a raspberry pi where the end-user can add, remove and edit events. When the time matches the time of an event on the calendar, a python script activates one of the relays which will turn on a boiler.

The idea of the project is that it will be used for a central heating system for 7 individually heated rooms. An 8 channel relay will be connected to each of the boilers and the pi will activate them when necessary.

At the moment I am creating the UI which is the calendar. I can not find a solution for this problem and if there is no solution, I do not know how to code a solution though I am willing to code it myself.

Comment: do you mean that there is no solution to check the current datetime with any other datetime ?

Comment: Cron may be what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is the other datetimes will change. Each week, an event will happen at a different time so how can I solve this without changing the code everytime

Comment: what does cron do?

Comment: [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)